# Date format changed using seaborn pointplot

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, seaborn, visualization

When I use seaborn to draw a pointplot, the date on the x-axis changes to this strange format `2020-01-06T00:00:00.000000000`. The dates from the 'Current Year Week Ending' column are converted to DateTime object before drawing this figure. My other graph (lineplot) uses similar inputs and format, but it doesn't have this issue, the dates are like `2020-01-06`.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

*The `total_us` dataframe and `sub` dataframe I use in my plots are subsets of the same dataset. And I converted the date on that big dataset before creating those two subsets. So the value in 'Current Year Week Ending' column of `total_us` and `sub` should have the same DateTime format.

```
#create a pointplot to capture the variability                             
plt.figure(figsize = (8, 6))                                                  
sns.pointplot(x = 'Current Year Week Ending',                                               
              y = 'ASP Current Year', 
              hue ='Type', 
              data = sub, 
              markers=["o", "x"],
              linestyles=["-", "--"])                                
plt.xticks(rotation=45, horizontalalignment='right', fontweight='light', fontsize='medium')
plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis='y')
```

[image]

```
#create a lineplot 
plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))
sns.lineplot(x='Current Year Week Ending', 
             y='Total Bulk and Bags Units', 
             hue='Type', 
             data = total_us);
plt.xticks(rotation=45, horizontalalignment='right', fontweight='light', fontsize='medium')
plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis='y')
```

[image]

this is what `sub` looks like, so the values in 'Current Year Week Ending' column are like "2020-01-06". I don't know why it changes when I draw a pointplot.
[image]

Comment: You are using two different data source ...the index is different

Comment: Hi Sophie, welcome to SO! In general it is better to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help others reproduce your issue.

Comment: sorry, I should clarify. The total_us dataframe and sub dataframe are subsets of the same dataset. And I converted the date on that big dataset before creating those two subsets.

Comment: What are the outputs from sub.index and total_us.index?

Comment: `@Derek O` Int64Index([  10,   19,   24,   27,   29,   35,   36,   46,   55,   65,
            ...
            1662, 1674, 1679, 1683, 1688, 1692, 1697, 1707, 1715, 1725],
           dtype='int64', length=256) for sub.index

Comment: And for total_us.index ? If they're from subsetted from the same source I assume they should be the same, but it never hurts to check

Comment: `@ Derek O`Int64Index([  30,   84,  138,  191,  246,  271,  353,  406,  462,  527,  569,
             595,  678,  703,  784,  839,  895,  959, 1002, 1067, 1110, 1164,
            1217, 1271, 1302, 1355, 1444, 1450, 1556, 1580, 1653, 1687],
           dtype='int64') for total_us. They are different subsets from the dataset, so index are different.

Comment: Oh I see - you haven't indexed the dataframes by date. What is the type for the date column? If the date column is the first column, what do you get for sub.iloc[:, 0] and  total_us.iloc[:, 0]

Comment: `@DerekO` so the type is datetime64[ns].

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216315/discussion-between-derek-o-and-sophie-lou).

Answer (score 1):

I think your date column may just include these trailing zeros, and seaborn deals with it differently depending on how much room there is on the plot. So try the following for your date column:

```
sub.iloc[:,1] = sub.iloc[:,1].dt.strftime('Y/%m/%d')
```

If for some reason that doesn't fix the problem (perhaps seaborn point plots and line plots do something different under the hood), then a possible workaround would be to split the text `2020-01-06T00:00:00.000000000` at the letter 'T' and throw out the trailing zeros after. We can use the fact that `sns.pointplot` returns a `matplotlib.Axes` object (from the [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pointplot.html)), setting the variable ax equal to your point plot:

```
ax = sns.pointplot(x = 'Current Year Week Ending',                                               
          y = 'ASP Current Year', 
          hue ='Type', 
          data = sub, 
          markers=["o", "x"],
          linestyles=["-", "--"]) 
ax.set_xticklabels([date_text.get_text().split("T")[0] for date_text in ax.get_xticklabels()])
```